# How to hide query strings from url in php?

Tags: php, url, query-string

Im trying to make a message system and when the receiver is reading a message theres a link to reply the message, as follow:

```
<a href=mail.php?action=compose&toid='".urlencode($viewrow['sender'])."'&subject='RE:+".urlencode($viewrow['subject'])."'&message=".urlencode($viewrow['message']).">Reply</a>
```

The sender, subject and message are being retrieved from mysql.

The user is seeing something like:

```
http://www.somesite.com/author/mail.php?action=compose&toid='8'&subject='RE:+test+subject'&message=test+message
```

What i need to know is if theres a way to hide the subject and the message from reply url, so the user will see on address bar only:

```
http://www.somesite.com/author/mail.php?action=compose&toid='8'
```

This is how the subject, message and id is being retrieved from db.

```
//view message
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == inbox) { 
        if(isset($_GET['viewid'])) { 
            $viewid = $_GET['viewid'];
    /*      $viewsql = "select * from mail where reciever='".$userid."' and mail_id=".$viewid; */
            $viewsql = "select * from mail, authors where (mail.sender = authors.id) and (mail.reciever = '".$userid."') and (mail.reciever_deleted ='0') and mail.mail_id = ".$viewid;
            $viewquery = mysql_query($viewsql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
            $viewrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($viewquery);
            if ($viewrow['reciever'] == $userid) { //check if user is the reciever
            } else { 
                header('Location: mail.php?action=inbox');
                exit; 
            } 
            echo "<h3>Lendo mensagem particular da Caixa de Entrada</h3>";
            echo "<table align=\"center\" width=\"75%\" class=\"sortable\">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2' style=\"text-align:center;font-weight:normal;\">Mensagem particular enviada por ".$viewrow['displayname']." em ".date('d/m/y',strtotime($viewrow['created_at'])).".</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'>
                            <img style=\"float:left;padding: 5px 15px 5px 2px;width: 65px;\" src=\"".$viewrow['gravatar']."\" alt=\"".$viewrow['displayname']."\" title=\"".$viewrow['displayname']."\" />
                            <div style=\"padding: 8px 5px 2px;\"><span style=\"font-size:1.6em;\">&#8594; </span><b>".$viewrow['subject']."</b></div>
                            <div style=\"padding: 8px 30px 8px 85px;\">".nl2br($viewrow['message'])."<br /></div>
                            <span style=\"float:right;\">
                                <a href=mail.php?action=compose&toid='".urlencode($viewrow['sender'])."'&subject='RE:+".urlencode($viewrow['subject'])."'&message=".urlencode($viewrow['message']).">Responder</a> | <a href=javascript:confirmDelete('mail.php?action=inbox&deleteid=".$viewid."')>Apagar</a>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>";

            // mark as read by reciever
            $query="update mail set mail_status='read' where reciever = '$userid' and mail_id = '$viewid'"; 
            mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
        }                   
    }elseif (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == outbox) { ...
```

I know i need to use post, but how?

I tried but could not make it work.

Sorry for my stupidity..

Comment: Use `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: You will probably be able to get the subject and content of the post if you have the ID, right? Be sure to remove the single quotes from the url.

Comment: i tried to use POST but no success, maybe my retrieve is not right. I dont know, im new into this...

Comment: @DannyBeckett GET/POST is no issue as the code shown is the one that fetches and displays messages, while the question relates to a provided link to a reply script.

Comment: Replace the reply link with a form having a submit button and hidden fields for the information now included in the URL

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sent information to a page by an `<a>` using POST.
But you can do it with JavaScript or a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide query strings, but you can send the data via POST instead, which isn't visible in the address bar. To do this you will need to submit your data using a form; while Pietroalbini is correct that you cannot use an `a` element, you can style a `button` to look identical with trivial difficulty:

```
<style>
button {
    background:none;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
    color: blue;
    padding:0;        
}
</style>

<form action="script.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="Test"/>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```